# Index Out of Bound Exception Occurence

Tags: java, exception, indexoutofboundsexception

In the below code I'm getting the following error :

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
```

The size is 1 for copiedppList.size()

```
for (int domainData = 0; domainData < copiedppList.size(); domainData++) {
    if (domainData == 0) {
        firstValue.setNewValue(firstValue.getFieldValue());
        DomainItemFieldHistory oldValue = copiedppList.get(domainData + 1);
        if (firstValue.getFieldID().equals(oldValue.getFieldID())) {
            firstValue.setOldValue(oldValue.getFieldValue());
        }
    }
}
```

The below line is causing the mentioned issue:

```
DomainItemFieldHistory oldValue = copiedppList.get(domainData + 1);
```

How can i avoid this?
What condition can be added to prevent the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the terminating condition to `copiedppList.size() - 1` will prevent the out of bounds exception.

Array indexes are zero based, so the last valid index is `size() - 1`. The posted code can iterate to `size() - 1` but makes the following call:

```
copiedppList.get(domainData + 1);
```

causing the exception.

If the loop must iterate over all elements then you need to protect the `+ 1` call. For example:

```
if (domainData < copiedppList.size() - 1)
{
    copiedppList.get(domainData + 1); // This is now safe, assuming
                                      // nothing reduces the size of
                                      // copiedppList since the if check.
}
```

Comment: i need copiedppList.size()  cannot do copiedppList.size() -1

Comment: @simpy, what is the intention of the loop?

Comment: the loop has to repeat upto copiedppList.size() ,it has some other logic to do

Answer (score 1):

Remove the +1.

`DomainItemFieldHistory oldValue = copiedppList.get(domainData)`

Comment: i need the incremented data in some cases so i have to add +1

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a change:

- either `get(domainData + 1);` => `get(domainData);`
- or `for (int domainData = 0; domainData < copiedppList.size(); domainData++)` => `for (int domainData = 0; domainData < copiedppList.size() - 1; domainData++)`

Reason: your list is indexed from 0 to size - 1, so at the last iteration of your loop, you are trying to call `list.get(size)` which fails as there is no such element.

Answer (score 1):

if `copiedppList.size() =  1` , only index 0 is valid

Answer (score 1):

> The size is 1 for copiedppList.size()

`.get(domainData + 1);` will cause it to ask data at index location [1] that is more than the specified size.

Keep it `.get(domainData);`

Answer (score 1):

Since

copiedppList.size() is `0`

so in that case you cannot access

```
copiedppList.get(domainData + 1);
```

when `domainData == 0`

You need to check that you have more than one entry in the collection:

```
if (domainData == 0 && copiedppList.size() > 1) {
```